# Unable to fetch a value from multi-select input texbox in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have created a textbox that has a "+" (Add button) and a "-" (delete button) . And when i click on + , i get one more text-box . And when i click on - , i delete that textbox with its value. To capture the value of the text-box , i use ngModel. I tried it without using a Form. Here the issues i am facing are  -

[1.]

When i click on '+' button, i get the textbox successfully and i get its value also. But for subsequent additions when done using "+' button, i get the same value . And when i change its value, the value changes on every other text box done using " + " button.

[2.] I don't know how to delete the value of the text-box from the array-variable.

Please help

code -
**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="addContainer">
  <p style="margin-left: 200px; font-size:18px">Please enter the API 
   Object -</p>

<table align="center">

    <tbody>

      <tr >

          <td  >
            <input  type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" [(ngModel)]= "firstValue">
          </td>
          <td  >
            <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOne(firstValue)" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="deleteOneMore()" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
          </td>

      </tr>


      <tr *ngFor="let container of containers; let i = index;" #myElement>
          <ng-container >
            <td  id="1myElement">
              <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" [(ngModel)]= "addedValue">
            </td>
            <td  id="1myElement">
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore($event)" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="deleteOneMore()" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>

      <tr>

        <td style="text-align:center">
          <button type="button" (click)="showGraphs(firstValue,addedValue)" class="btn btn-dark">Search</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
addOne(firstDropdValue) {

        console.log("inside addOne = firstDropdValue = ", 
      firstDropdValue);

        this.addMore = true;
        this.containers.push(this.containers.length);

    }

  addOneMore(addedValue)
    {
        this.moreValues.push(addedValue);

        console.log("Inside AddOneMore More Values = ", 
      this.moreValues);

    }
    deleteOneMore(){

        this.containers.splice(this.index, 1);
    }


    showGraphs(firstV, addedV) {
        console.log("inside showGraphs()");
        console.log("firstValue =", firstV, "addedValue = ", addedV);
        this.showEwayBill = true;
        this.showCollection = true;
        this.EwayBill();
        this.Collection();
    }
```

Image -

[image: Image of text-boxes]

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain an array for the newly added values like below and your `add` and `remove` should look like below

```
values = ["sometext"];

addOneMore() {
  this.values.push("sivakumar");
}

deleteOneMore(index) {
  this.values.splice(index, 1);
}
```

In the template file you can use that `values` or `containers` array to loop like below

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="" [(ngModel)]='values[0]'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore(firstValue)" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="deleteOneMore(i)" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let value of values; let i = index;">
    <tr *ngIf="i > 0">
      <td id="1myElement">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" [(ngModel)]="values[i]">
      </td>
      <td id="1myElement">
        <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore()" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="deleteOneMore(i)" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

But, in this solution, still there is one issue that, in the textbox, we are allowing to enter one word at a time, I am not able to figure it out the reason, if anyone can, welcoming you to edit the answer ;-)

Working stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dz8phr)